# Cannot get my current location while using a real phone

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get my current location and add an marker on the postion. When I start my application on a emulator everything works. But when I build APK and I start application on my phone, I don't see the marker on the current postion. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
 private void loadmap() {
        mapFragement.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                MainActivity.this.googleMap = googleMap;
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker = new LatLng(36.749979, 5.040646)).title("fastpark"));



            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMS_CALL_ID) {
            checkPermmisions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (lm != null) {
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        start = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(start);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        //move map camera
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(start));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there an error in your **logcat**?

Comment: No. everthing is good

Comment: Meaby your phone version cant support the codes version? (Lower than MIN API)?

Comment: It works when I give the position but when i try to get my crurent pos i don't have the marker on my position

Comment: I dont know this type of stuff. I was trying to point out possible non code solutions. Somebody will help you shortly

Comment: This question needs attention.